# Xvfb + ffmpeg/aconv not working

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ffmpeg, xvfb, avconv

I'm trying to capture screen using xvfb + aconv.
I''m using docker to run image. I've tried almost everything to make it working, different ubuntu images Debian Centos, different images from docker hub.
My last build is simple ubuntu:trusty(14.04) image + xvfb + avconv

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d//mozillateam-firefox-next-trusty.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CE49EC21
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y firefox xvfb python-pip
RUN pip install selenium
RUN mkdir -p /root/selenium_wd_tests
#ADD sel_wd_new_user.py /root/selenium_wd_tests
ADD xvfb.init /etc/init.d/xvfb
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/xvfb
RUN update-rc.d xvfb defaults
```

I installed avcnov through apt-get
then I run Xvfb

```
Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24
```

and firefox 
Then I just run

```
avconv -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1280x1024 -i :99 -vcodec libx264 -threads 4 $HOME/output.avi
```

and nothing happens, avconv is stuck it doesn't starts capturing

```
avconv version 9.20-6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Dec  7 2016 21:22:31 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
[x11grab @ 0x2189c60] device: :99 -> display: :99 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1280 height: 1024
```

Anybody please any advice, i've spent 4 days trying to make it work.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why your setup does not work. But if your goal is just to see what firefox does, you may try out [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) to run firefox in container and being able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only thing i should know about it all before start that `ctrl+z` doesn't brings tasks to background. That was my problem.